# JMH, Gradle - Error: Could not find or load main class org.openjdk.jmh.runner.ForkedMain

Tags: java, gradle, build, classloader, jmh

**Details:**

1. I use Gradle as my build system.
2. I need to run microbenchmarks when "main" application is running. (Due to bad architecture using adapters everywhere, there is no way to do dummies) My running method is:

```java
public void benchmark() throws RunnerException {
        getLogger().info("Starting microbenchmarks with JMH...");
        Options opts = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(ElectricGroupBenchmark.class.getSimpleName())
                .forks(1)
                .threads(1)
                .build();
        new Runner(opts).run();
}
```

3. Application I am developing is loaded by "main" application using class loader, so I don't need to shade its API and some other dependencies, that's why I don't use [gradle jmh plugin](https://github.com/melix/jmh-gradle-plugin), if I try to add dependencies using `jmhCompileOnly` then jmhJar will fail because plugin's sub-task generating jmh classes wouldn't deal with API classes that's not shaded in jar. Instead I use:

```
    implementation group: 'org.openjdk.jmh', name: 'jmh-core', version: '1.33'
    annotationProcessor group: 'org.openjdk.jmh', name: 'jmh-generator-annprocess', version: '1.33'
```

And this simple options to shade JMH into jar:

```
jar {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)}
    }
}
```

If I try to run benchmarks while my "main" application is running and loaded this jar with microbenchmarks, I'll get:

```
[17:13:58 INFO]: # JMH version: 1.33
[17:13:58 INFO]: # VM version: JDK 17.0.1, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 17.0.1+12-jvmci-21.3-b05
[17:13:58 INFO]: # VM invoker: /usr/lib/jvm/graalvm-ce-java17-21.3.0/bin/java
[17:13:58 INFO]: # VM options: -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=1 -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+EnableJVMCIProduct -XX:-UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -javaagent:/home/denery/IdeaProjects/ElectricityMBenchmarks/.server/paper-1.17.1-400.jar -Xms1G -Xmx1G -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=RU -Duser.language=ru -Duser.variant
[17:13:58 INFO]: # Blackhole mode: full + dont-inline hint (default, use -Djmh.blackhole.autoDetect=true to auto-detect)
[17:13:58 INFO]: # Warmup: 3 iterations, 10 s each
[17:13:58 INFO]: # Measurement: 3 iterations, 10 s each
[17:13:58 INFO]: # Timeout: 10 min per iteration
[17:13:58 INFO]: # Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
[17:13:58 INFO]: # Benchmark mode: Average time, time/op
[17:13:58 INFO]: # Benchmark: ru.worldm.electricity.benchmarks.ElectricGroupBenchmark.connectBenchmark
[17:13:58 INFO]: 
[17:13:58 INFO]: # Run progress: 0,00% complete, ETA 00:01:00
[17:13:58 INFO]: # Fork: 1 of 1
[17:13:58 INFO]: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=1 may require system level permission, e.g., being the root user. If the necessary permission is not possessed, changes to priority will be silently ignored.
[17:14:00 INFO]: Error: Could not find or load main class org.openjdk.jmh.runner.ForkedMain
[17:14:00 INFO]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openjdk.jmh.runner.ForkedMain
[17:14:00 INFO]: <forked VM failed with exit code 1>
[17:14:00 INFO]: <stdout last='20 lines'>
[17:14:00 INFO]: </stdout>
[17:14:00 INFO]: <stderr last='20 lines'>
[17:14:00 INFO]: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=1 may require system level permission, e.g., being the root user. If the necessary permission is not possessed, changes to priority will be silently ignored.
[17:14:00 INFO]: Error: Could not find or load main class org.openjdk.jmh.runner.ForkedMain
[17:14:00 INFO]: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openjdk.jmh.runner.ForkedMain
[17:14:00 INFO]: </stderr>
[17:14:00 INFO]: 
[17:14:00 INFO]: # Run complete. Total time: 00:00:00
[17:14:00 INFO]: 
[17:14:00 INFO]: REMEMBER: The numbers below are just data. To gain reusable insights, you need to follow up on
[17:14:00 INFO]: why the numbers are the way they are. Use profilers (see -prof, -lprof), design factorial
[17:14:00 INFO]: experiments, perform baseline and negative tests that provide experimental control, make sure
[17:14:00 INFO]: the benchmarking environment is safe on JVM/OS/HW level, ask for reviews from the domain experts.
[17:14:00 INFO]: Do not assume the numbers tell you what you want them to tell.
[17:14:00 INFO]: 
[17:14:00 INFO]: Benchmark  Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
```

But org.openjdk.jmh.runner.ForkedMain is shaded into my Jar which is loaded my "main" application, what's problem in there?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar use case where because of the architecture the benchmarks were being run on the application, and it was evident from the JMH log (use verbose mode for more logs) that the fork is running with the classpath which was missing the ForkedMain class.

So if we tried moving the `jmh-core` library to the classpath the next issue was `ERROR: Unable to find the resource: /META-INF/BenchmarkList` because the fork wasn't able to find the BenchmarkList, again because of the way the application was architected.

Even though it is not recommended, but you can try setting the forks to 0 by `.forks(0)` or `@Forks(0)` and that should perform the test under the same process. (Forks are used to normalize the run-to-run variance)

Additional note: Also, the JMH won't help you out with the dependency injection, so you will have to manually ensure that the corresponding required dependencies are present for the test when you are not working with dummies